# SharePoint List element creator must have full access permission

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list, when someone creates a new element on this list I want to give him full access on this element to allows him to manage permissions especially on this element. Is there a way to set default permission for the element creator on a SharePoint list ?

Thx,

Maxime

Answer (score 0):

You could grant unique permission to the user for the item.

Select the item -> Show actions -> Manage access -> Grant full control permission to the user for the item.

[image]

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.